# ¿Cómo saber el largo en bytes de un archivo de texto plano?

Tags: c#, array

Tengo un código el cual, abre documentos `.txt`, para abrirlos debo utilizar el `binaryreader`, para guardas el archivo en un `byte[]`, el problema está, en que no se como obtener el `lenght`, de mi archivo, para determinar el tamaño del `byte[]`, ya que el archivo no va a ser siempre el mismo.

Adjunto código

```
string path = @"C:\prueba.txt";+
byte[]    dat = new byte[];

BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(File.Open(path,FileMode.Open));
int conta = 1;
int count = 0;
while (conta > 0)
{
    if(reader.Read() == -1)
    {
        conta = -1;
    }
    else
    {
        byte[count] dat = new byte[reader.Read()];
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Estas usando C#, cierto? Tambien te recomiendo hacer el recorrido de la pagina https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que entiendas mejor como funciona. Otro vistazo a la ayuda de como preguntar tambien te vendra bien. https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: así es, obviamente el código me da errores pero es para que se tengan una idea de lo que quiero hacer

Comment: Hola, puedes usar el método File.ReadAllBytes(string path) para leer el archivo y generar un array de bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Pudieras utilizar el metodo [`System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.io.file.readallbytes(v=vs.110).aspx) que te retorna los bytes el archivo y con la propiedad [`.Length`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.length(v=vs.110).aspx) puedes obtener el tamaño.

```
byte[] archivo =System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(rutaArchivo);
var tamaño = archivo.Lenght;
```

Comment: `Lenth` no es correcto al parecer tiene un error `length` quizá ?

Comment: Corregido. Muchísimas gracias @Dev.Joel.

Answer (score 1):

La mejor manera es usar la classe FileInfo que te proporciona System.IO

```
new FileInfo(fileName).Length
```

Le preguntas por la propietat Length y voilà!

Lo he provado en mono pero es lo mismo, aquí está mi código para ver exactamente el número de bytes.

```
String fileName = @"/home/marc/Escritorio/file";
Console.WriteLine(new FileInfo(fileName).Length);
```

Espero que te ayude!

Answer (score 0):

puedes usar el método `File.ReadAllBytes(string path)` para leer el archivo y generar un array de bytes.

Comment: ¿Y cómo sería el código para responder a la pregunta? La idea es aportar contenido con la mayor calidad posible.

Answer (score 0):

Dado que ya haces una llamada a `File.Open`, puedes usar el resultado para obtener la longitud:

```
// BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(File.Open(path,FileMode.Open));
var fileStream = File.Open(path,FileMode.Open);
var length = fileStream.Length;
BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(fileStream);
```

De esta forma es posible tener el tamaño antes de leer la totalidad del archivo y de forma más sencilla que usando FileInfo (que también es correcto).

---

Lo que me recuerda... debes cerrar el archivo. Una sentencia [using](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) podría encargarse de eso.

---

Sin embargo, dado que tu objetivo es leer la totalidad del archivo, `File.ReadAllBytes` te ahorra la necesidad de saber el tamaño de antemano (y también la de cerrar el archivo). Luego puedes leer la longitud como lo muestra la [respuesta de Einer](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/82872/377).